# filled.contour - delineate the change in the z value levels

Tags: r, graphics

I have to produce `filled.contour` plots that have some kind of symmetry in the z-values like in the below code

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 1:5
z <- matrix(outer(x,y,"+"),nrow=5)
filled.contour(x,y,z)
filled.contour(x,y,z,color.palette=rainbow)
z2 <- z
z2[5,5] <- Inf
filled.contour(x,y,z2,col=rainbow(200),nlevels=200)
```

I would like to be able to delineate the levels of the z value for example certain levels or increments (2,4,6,8,10) increments so as to obtain the following plot

[image]

I want to leave the levels of `col=rainbow(200)` in order to plot smooth colors and color transitions but I want to delineate certain values/increments.

Is this possible? I would appreciate a base R solution but in case this is not possible any solution would be good (ggplot, lattice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use countourLines() to add the lines and text() to add the text:

```
txtlab <- c("2", "4", "6", "8", "Inf")
txtpos <- c(1.25, 2, 3, 4, 4.75)
ctlns <- contourLines(x, y, z2, levels=c(3, 5, 7, 9))
filled.contour(x,y,z2,col=rainbow(200),nlevels=200, 
     plot.axes={axis(1); axis(2); text(txtpos, txtpos, txtlab, cex=1.5);
     sapply(1:4, function(x) lines(ctlns[[x]][[2]], ctlns[[x]][[3]], lwd=2))
})
```

[image: Filled contour]

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. Does this allow also for lines that are now straight but curved?

Comment: Yes, the contourLines() function will construct curved contour lines as well.

Comment: Fantastic! I am going to give the answer to you since this answer does not mess with the legend. Great use of sapply too! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is black for every whole number (using an example from is.integer), which could be modified to only return `black` for even whole numbers quite easily:

```
getcolor <- function(z, n) {
  is.wholenumber <-
    function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)  abs(x - round(x)) < tol
  pp <- pretty(range(z, finite=TRUE), n)
  ifelse(is.wholenumber(pp), 'black', rainbow(n))
}

filled.contour(x,y,z2,col=getcolor(z2, 200),nlevels=200)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very clever approach. You integrate the line drawing in the color. I have two questions. 1. I would like to specify myself the ranges/intervals (and not rely on 'pretty' ). 2. Does this approach allow for curved lives? 3. Is it possible for the black lines not to be drawn on the legend?. Thanks a lot

Comment: 1: There does not seem to be separate color parameters for the legend and the plot, the answer seems to be no.  2: There aren't really any lines; if the shape z == constant is curved, the black will also curve.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something like that recently and I used that type of code:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 1:5
z <- matrix(outer(x,y,"+"),nrow=5)
z2 <- z
z2[5,5] <- Inf
filled.contour(x,y,z2,col=rainbow(200),nlevels=200
plot.axis = {axis(1);axis(2);contour(x,y,z2,add=TRUE)}) #that's when you add the contours
```

[Result (click on link to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkWEd.png)